# Dealing with image not found

Tags: angularjs

In AngularJS, how can I load a different image, if the one specified at first could not be found? In the case at hand, I have a slug, and don't know what the file extension will be. It could e.g. be png, jpg, svg.

What I want to do is:

```
<img ng-src="images/{{slug}}" />
```

And then I want it to go and check

```
images/{{slug}}.png
images/{{slug}}.jpg
images/{{slug}}.svg
```

until it has found a file that exists.

Is there a function that fires if an image could not be loaded?

Comment: If the images are being served by your server I think that the server should be in charge of determining the correct extension.  If you're just guessing, I don't think there's any great way to do this... Any approach would be just as ugly as if you weren't using Angular.

Comment: Solved now thanks to sylwester.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi Ben you create directive like that  http://plnkr.co/edit/Bp47O0sqyO10mZGDiVGh?p=preview

**FUNCTION TO CHECK IF IMAGE EXIST:**

```
function imageExists(url, callback) {
  var img = new Image();
  img.onload = function() {
    callback(true);
  };
  img.onerror = function() {
    callback(false);
  };
  img.src = url;
}
```

**DIRECTIVE:**

```
angular.module('app').directive('fallbackSrc', [fallbackSrc]);

    function fallbackSrc() {

      var fallbackSrc = {
        scope: {
          fsrc: '@'

        },
        link: function postLink(scope, elem, attr) {
          var ext = ['.png', '.svg', '.jpg'];

          existingImage = ext.some(function(extension ) {
            var imageUrl = scope.fsrc + extension;

            imageExists(imageUrl, function(exists) {
              if (exists) {
                angular.element(elem).attr("src", imageUrl);
                return true;
}

            });

          });

        }
      };
      return fallbackSrc;


    };
```

**HTML:**

```
 <img fallback-src fsrc="http://www.google.com/images/srpr/nav_logo14" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<object data="images/{{slug}}.png" type="image/png">
   <img ng-src="images/{{slug }}" />
 </object>
```

Comment: How do I make it work for multiple file extension, i.e. jpg and svg? If I just copy this code multiple times, it will be the same as simply putting the img multiple times, i.e. I will get image-not-found boxes.